# How to correct this IndentationError?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I receive an IndentationError: unindent does not match outher indentation level).  I wrote the following code

```
if in_files[idx] not in results_dic:
              results_dic[in_files[idx]] = [pet_label]

           else print("** Warning: Duplicate files exist in directory:" , in_files[idx])

else print("** Warning: Duplicate files exist in directory:"  in_files[idx])
```

I want to get rid of the IndentationError, Please can someone help me. Thank you.

Comment: You have problem with formatting (mixing tabs and spaces, different number of spaces). It's hard to tell if you included it without formatting

Comment: Even after fixing the indentation error, this code is not syntactically valid. `else` needs a colon, you can't have two `else`s on one `if`, and there's a missing comma in the second `print(...)`. [I know this question is old, I'm just writing this for reference if any beginners stumble onto this.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your code is already in the form below, check that line 2 and 4 use only **tabs** or **spaces**.
Confirm that you did not use **tab** for one line and **spaces** for another line.
If you used **spaces** for both lines 2 and 4, confirm that you indented by exactly the same number of **spaces**.
For lines 1 and 3, confirm that there is no **space** at the beginning of either line.

```
if in_files[idx] not in results_dic:
    results_dic[in_files[idx]] = [pet_label]
else:
    print("** Warning: Duplicate files exist in directory:", in_files[idx])
```

Answer (score 0):

Indentations are important in python, you can't just do whatever spacing you want. Also be careful using the `[Tab]` key as it may insert a tab character (`\t`) which is different then a `[Space]`.

```
if in_files[idx] not in results_dic:
    results_dic[in_files[idx]] = [pet_label]
else:
    print("** Warning: Duplicate files exist in directory:" , in_files[idx])
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as an update, you can probably optimize your code as so. Note that I assumed some things about your missing code.

```
results_dic = {}
in_files = [.....]
pet_label = '....'
for idx in in_files:
    file = in_files[idx]
    if file not in results_dic:
        results_dic[file] = [pet_label]
    else:
        print("** Warning: Duplicate files exist in directory:", file)
```